# s:url taking all the params even param name is different

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

Hi I am using `s:url` tag for making a url, I need it to paginate my jsp to several pages.
So I need to send next or previous when we click on next or previous link. But when I click on Previous it shows me url on address bar like `someAction?previuos=prev` then I click on Next it displays `someAction?previuos=prev&Next=Next` when I only need `someAction?Next=Next`.

I have given different names to the url as for Previous link `<s:url name="urlPrev">` and for next `<s:url name="urlNext">`

I don't how to differentiate them. What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The `<s:url/>` tag should default to the current action, without any parameters. You should just be able to say in your page:

```
<s:url>
   <s:param name="Next" value="'Next'"/>
</s:url>

<s:url>
   <s:param name="Previous" value="'Previous'"/>
</s:url>
```

Note that the `<s:a/>` tag behaves much like the  tag excepting that it produces an html anchor of course so put the link name in the body. This should solve your tag issues...

Just to point out paging is roughly done on web sites by passing parameters which account for start_index and number_of_records_per_page. The "Next" button then simply adds number_of_records_per_page + 1 for the value of start_index for next. To decrement subtract number_of_records_per_page. By standardising the names all list based actions become easier to write.

Consult http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1.2/docs/tag-reference.html for use of these tags (one thing to note is the name parameter is not listed as a property for the url tag).